# how to implement google sign in react-native using expressjs and passportjs

Tags: android, react-native, express, passport.js, google-signin

I have my web apps which use google authentication configured via `passportjs` in my `express` backend. Now i want to create react-native apps for the same. I am trying to implement google signin using same apis, but it is not working.

On my backend:

1. I have `/auth/google` endpoint which triggers the google signin page
2. on success it redirects back to a callback url `/auth/google/callback`
3. then it redirects back to the frontend(client) url.

Now in case of react-native apps, i open the `/auth/google` in a webview, which triggers the google signin page, on success it gets to callback url and then while redirecting back to frontend(client), i do res.redirect(myapp://app/login), but it shows `Cannot GET /auth/google/myapp:app//login`.

Comment: The issue you're facing because the way you're trying to handle the redirect URL in your React Native app. When you use a WebView to authenticate with Google, the WebView will try to load the redirect URL within itself. However, in a React Native app, you don't have a server to handle the redirect URL, so you need to handle this in your React Native code.

Comment: i want to do the google auth using passportjs in react-native. i am able to select the google account and come back to app, but i am facing some cookie issue where the passport's deserialize function is not triggering. I have manally sent back the cookie to app and set it using react-native-cookies/cookies, and each time i sent request i sent this cookies with it. but passportjs is not able to deserialize the user from this cookie session. any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to redirect back to app using `res.redirect("intent://app/login#Intent;scheme=myapp;package=com.myapp;end")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use following SDK for google authentication in react native which does't required backend API or webView:

```
  yarn add  @react-native-google-signin/google-signin
```

call config method in early stage like App.js

```
 import { GoogleSignin } from '@react-native-google-signin/google- 
  signin';

  GoogleSignin.configure(); // you can also setup custom config
```

then you can use you SDK any where like this:

```
  // import statusCodes along with GoogleSignin
  import { GoogleSignin, statusCodes } from '@react-native-google- 
 signin/google-signin';

 // Somewhere in your code
 signIn = async () => {
  try {
 await GoogleSignin.hasPlayServices();
 const userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
 setState({ userInfo });
  } catch (error) {
 if (error.code === statusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
  // user cancelled the login flow
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.IN_PROGRESS) {
   // operation (e.g. sign in) is in progress already
  } else if (error.code === statusCodes.PLAY_SERVICES_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
  // play services not available or outdated
  } else {
   // some other error happened
   }
  }
  };
```

you can also visit SDK documentation :[@react-native-google-signin/google-signin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-google-signin/google-signin?activeTab=explore)

Comment: i want to do the google auth using passportjs in react-native. i am able to select the google account and come back to app, but i am facing some cookie issue where the passport's deserialize function is not triggering. I have manally sent back the cookie to app and set it using react-native-cookies/cookies, and each time i sent request i sent this cookies with it. but passportjs is not able to deserialize the user from this cookie session. any help?